# PowerApps - ifblank with button does not work

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I had a function in PowerApps:

SubmitForm(Form1) && SubmitForm(Form2),

ResetForm(Form1) && ResetForm(Form2),
Navigate(Screen4;Fade))

This function was on the button, and it was responsible for sending forms, resetting data and showing the "complete" window.

I would however want to change this function so it would work only if Form1 is not blank (form 1 is a sharepoint multitext  field that is required).

I tried to do it like that:

```
If(
IsBlank(Form1),
DisplayMode.Disabled,
DisplayMode.Edit
else
SubmitForm(Form1) && SubmitForm(Form2);;
ResetForm(Form1) && ResetForm(Form2);;
Navigate(Screen4;Fade)
)
```

or like that:

```
If( ! IsBlank( Form1),
SubmitForm(Form1) && SubmitForm(Form2);;
ResetForm(Form1) && ResetForm(Form2);;
Navigate(Screen4;Fade))
```

but I am getting ParenClose...

Could you please help me in making it work? I would love to have button greyed out if the Form1 does not have at least 1 symbol.

Comment: note that for some locales (e.g. Europe) "," is replaced by a ";" and ";" by ";;"

Answer (score 0):

> Form 1 is a sharepoint multitext  field that is required

The blank statement needs to evaluate the string inside the field so you would need Form1.text

```
IsBlank(Form1.text)
```